# Which ruby methods free GVL?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.6

In multi-threaded ruby execution, you cannot get parallel execution of threads unless you use those functions which frees GVL.

In my understanding, following ruby methods frees GVL:

- `Kernel#sleep`
- `IO#read` and `IO#write`

#### Question

- In pure ruby, is there any other methods which frees GVL?

#### Version

- I'm currently using ruby version 2.6, so expect the info of this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked same question on stackoverflow (Japanese).

Got this answer https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/55579/754 , which stating that

> - Bignum's div / modulo
> - Dir.new/Dir.open
> - Dir.chdir
> - Dir.rmdir
> - Dir.empty?
> - Dir.glob
> - File.chown
> - File's methods which check file status, namely stats
> - File.rename
> - File.truncate
> - File.mkfifo
> - IO.copy_stream
> - IO.#open and IO.#close related codes (was too complex to understand)
> - Kernel.#system
> - Kernel.#exec
>
> and in other standard libraries such as fiddle, openssl, readline, socket, zlib actually calls method which frees GVL.

this great answer was written by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944814/raccy

Answer (score 0):

> In pure ruby, is there any other methods which frees GVL?

In pure Ruby, there is no such thing as a GVL. The GVL is a feature of some specific versions of one specific implementation of Ruby. The *vast majority* of Ruby implementations don't have a GVL or even something remotely similar.

> I'm currently using ruby version 2.6, so expect the info of this version.

This is true for all versions of Ruby. No version of Ruby has ever specified the existence of a GVL. And it is highly doubtful that any future version of Ruby will, either.

Comment: I guess by "pure Ruby" the question's author actually ment MRI.

Comment: This answer is very misguided. Most interpreted language interpreters make use of a GVL, including Ruby MRI since 1.x through to 3.x.  Custom ruby interpreters such as Rubinius and JRuby try to allow true parallel processing.